# Excel 10 - Adding per client code

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel-table with 30.000+ lines I need to add up the values linked to the following client-codes :

```
CL_10074    1.747.692
CL_10077    74.748
CL_10080    199.597
CL_10080    1.994.525
CL_10080    2.292.350
CL_10081    614.026
CL_10081    145.233
CL_10085    1.337.151
```

I´d need the totals per client category, e.g. CL_10080 (3 entries) that´d be: 4.486.472, but for CL_10081 (only 2 entries): 759.259. Of course when there´s only one figure that one stays ´as is´.

Can anybody help out finding the formula how to add up per client code?

Many thanks!!
Joost

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your client code is in column `A`, the numbers to add in column `B` and a list of all unique client codes in column `D`, the use the following formula in column `E`

```
=SUMIF(A$1:A$30000,D1,B$1:B$30000)
```